# How to get minutes per hour for date range (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, count

I have a table like this, which contains the start time and end time of some process.

| start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-07-01 11:25:00 | 2019-07-01 11:40:00 |
| 2019-07-01 21:40:00 | 2019-07-01 22:10:00 |
| 2019-07-03 22:00:00 | 2019-07-04 22:00:00 |

And I would like to get, for each hour in between the `start_time` and `end_time`, a count of minutes that belong to that hour. In other words, I would like to know how many minutes the process was running for specified `end_hours`

For example, the first row would return something like this, since 15 minutes passed until end time 12:00.

| end_hour | total_minutes |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-07-01 12:00:00 | 15 |

Similarly, for the second row, the output would be

| end_hour | total_minutes |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-07-01 22:00:00 | 20 |
| 2019-07-01 23:00:00 | 10 |

For the final row, the output would be

| end_hour | total_minutes |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-07-03 23:00:00 | 60 |
| 2019-07-03 00:00:00 | 60 |
| 2019-07-04 01:00:00 | 60 |
| ... | ... |
| 2019-07-04 22:00:00 | 60 |

How do I achieve something like this in Python?

Comment: look up timedelta... you can get one by subtracting datetime from datetime.

Comment: You might want to add an approach you took to solve this by yourself (I understand it's not as trivial as subtracting the two datetime columns from each other). That could set a place to start, and potentially improve the quality of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The durations have minute precision, so let's up-sample to that frequency and count the minutes per hour that fall within one of the start_time - end_time intervals.

```
import pandas as  pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
       {"start_time": ["2019-07-01 11:25:00", "2019-07-01 21:40:00", "2019-07-03 22:00:00"],
        "end_time":   ["2019-07-01 11:40:00", "2019-07-01 22:10:00", "2019-07-04 22:00:00"]}
       )

df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])
df['end_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_time'])
df['minutes'] = (df['end_time'] - df['start_time']).dt.total_seconds()/60

# create an IntervalIndex which we can set as the axis (needed for re-indexing).
# subtract one minute from end_time so that the minute of the termination is excluded.
iv_idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df['start_time'],
                                      df['end_time']-pd.Timedelta(minutes=1),
                                      closed='both')

# create a new index with the extended frequency:
new_idx = pd.date_range(df['start_time'].min(), df['end_time'].max(), freq='min')

# set the new index to get the extended frequency;
# all minutes will have the value of the whole interval
result = df['minutes'].set_axis(iv_idx).reindex(new_idx)

# we can now calculate the duration per hour by resampling and summing the
# boolean representation of the duration (1/0):
result= result.fillna(0).astype(int).astype(bool).resample('H').sum()
result.index.name = 'start_hour'
```

Now you have the results anchored to start_hour (you can easily change to end hour by shifting the index by one hour):

```
print(result.loc["2019-07-01 11:00:00":"2019-07-01 12:00:00"])
# start_hour
# 2019-07-01 11:00:00    15
# 2019-07-01 12:00:00     0
# Freq: H, Name: minutes, dtype: int64

print(result.loc["2019-07-01 20:00:00":"2019-07-01 23:00:00"])
# start_hour
# 2019-07-01 20:00:00     0
# 2019-07-01 21:00:00    20
# 2019-07-01 22:00:00    10
# 2019-07-01 23:00:00     0
# Freq: H, Name: minutes, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_datetime` pandas built in function to convert the dates to datetime and the subtract end - start:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['2019-07-01 11:25:00','2019-07-01 11:40:00'], ['2019-07-01 21:40:00', '2019-07-01 22:10:00'], ['2019-07-03 22:00:00', '2019-07-04 22:00:00']], columns=['start_time', 'end_time'])
df['total_minutes'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['end_time']) - pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])).astype('timedelta64[m]')
>>> df
            start_time             end_time  total_minutes
0  2019-07-01 11:25:00  2019-07-01 11:40:00           15.0
1  2019-07-01 21:40:00  2019-07-01 22:10:00           30.0
2  2019-07-03 22:00:00  2019-07-04 22:00:00         1440.0
```

Comment: This gives me the total times between the `start_time` and `end_time`, but not broken down by whole hours in between the times